# getting / building strawberry perl.lib

Tags: perl, visual-c++, static-libraries

I have strawberry perl x64 installed for windows.
Unfortunately, i can't find a perl.xxx.lib. Only perl.5.16.2.dll.
I need the lib in order to write a perl-c++ wrapper with swig.
(The project needs the lib for linking)
Anyone knows what to do in order to get the lib (can i build it ?)
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command:

```
C> perl -V
```

This will produce a lot of output, and some of it might be useful for you. For example, part of my output was:

```
libc=, so=dll, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl516.a
```

The `libperl512.a` file was located under the `perl/lib/CORE` directory where I installed Strawberry Perl.

Is that what you're looking for? Otherwise, look at the [Config](http://perldoc.perl.org/Config.html) module and see if there's anything of interest. I did the following:

```
use Config;

print "$Config{_a}\n";
```

And it prints out `.a`.

Try this one for fun:

```
use Config;

for $key (sort keys %Config) {
    print "$key: $Config{$key}\n" if $Config{$key};
}
```

Somewhere in the output should be something interesting.

Comment: Hello,than you for answer.

Comment: Hello,thank you for answer. I am looking for perl.5.16.2.lib (Windows). This files is not part of installation and i can't build it or don't know how to build it. I need this library for linkage.The 1 script puts .a. The second a bunch of information. I need the .lib=static library on windows for linkage. The file libperl516.a is present. So it seems only linux libs are shipped with installation ? (even it is windows installation). Anyone know how to build this lib for windows ?

Comment: It seems i can use libperl516.a. It is a windows library built with gcc. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As David W pointed to:

libperl516.a

is what i am looking for. VC2008 can use it for linking.